# loop for tuple of list on python

Tags: python, loops

I have tuple of lists. The lengths of the lists are same each other. For example:

```
tol = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
```

I'd like to loop all pair of two lists like:

```
for v1, v2 in some_operation(tol):
    print "(%f, %f)" % (v1, v2)
```

The above code should print `(1,4)\n(2,5)\n(3,6)\n`.

One (little dirty) way is use zip

```
for v1, v2 in zip(tol[0], tol[1]):
    print...
```

Could you show me more simple way?

Comment: Not sure why you think `zip` is "dirty", but `zip(*tol)` looks "cleaner".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Zip would be simple and clean

```
tol = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6])

for v1, v2 in zip(*tol):
    print "(%d, %d)" % (v1, v2)
```

As you expect the output would be `(1,4)\n(2,5)\n(3,6)\n`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for v in zip(*tol):
    print "(%f, %f)" % (v[0], v[1])
```